# Session data Vs mysql query for small info

Tags: php, mysql, session, benchmarking

Cant find any sort of benchmarking, or tests, around this particular thing, so i'll just ask:

Needing a small amount of info (let's say that it's: "150", for example) that is stored or in the session, or in the mysql, that will need constant use to check if it remains the same, or changed, what will be more efficient, resource/server wise?

Pulling the data from session, or querying mysql?
(using PHP)

Thanks.

Comment: If you don't need the data to persist beyond the end of a session, it ought to be fairly obvious that using an RDBMS will just add unnecessary overhead.  With the (extremely limited) context given in the question, I would argue that one should just use PHP session variables.

Answer (score 0):

I would use MySQL queries to store this kind of data.

Reason: You will have more flexibility in case that you become more user. To many sessions can have an impact to your memory and data will be deleted when the user is closing his webbrowser.

Comment: Arguable and not completely correct: while I agree on the new-user-issue, sessions can last for a long time. Session cookie lifetime can be modified with [`session_set_cookie_params()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-cookie-params.php). Server-side session storage can be configured, too, and shouldn't be an issue unless you are facing thousands of users. Storing stuff in a database also requires space - and interacting with an RDBMS like MySQL adds a lot of overhead (connecting, query parsing, query execution, possibly transaction-overhead).